# Loop to overwrite Array only works one iteration

Tags: excel, vba

I am running a few nested loops like so

```
Worksheet Loop
    Apply AutoFilter to all unique values in COLUMN C
        Apply AutoFilter to all unique values in COLUMN D
            'Do some stuff
```

My goal was to create a 2-D array of unique values from `Column A` & `Column B` by copying the visible cells of a column, remove duplicates, and assign the remaining rows to an array. Then, I could simply loop through each array, filter as needed, and *do some stuff* to the visible cells.

---

For some reason, the second time I try to assign my `Column B` array, I get a  <kbd>type mismatch error</kbd>  on this line when trying to assign my temp array (`Get_Params`). When this happens, the value of `LR2 = 2` so that is not the issue.

Here is the master loop and the error is occurring on the function `Get_Params` on marked line

```
For Each ws In Worksheets
UnFilter ws
    If ws.Name <> "Temp" Then

        LR = ws.Range("C" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set Target = ws.Range("A1:P" & LR)
        Batches = Get_Batches(ws, LR)

        For b = LBound(Batches, 1) To UBound(Batches, 1)
        UnFilter ws

          Target.AutoFilter 3, Batches(b, 1)
          Params = Get_Params(ws, LR, Target)

              For p = LBound(Params, 1) To UBound(Params, 1)
                Target.AutoFilter 4, Params(p, 1)

                  'MsgBox TenPer(Target)

              Next p
        Next b

        LR = 0
        Set Target = Nothing
        UnFilter ws

    End If
Next ws
```

---

```
Function Get_Params(ws As Worksheet, LR As Long, Target As Range) As Variant()

Dim Temp As Worksheet: Set Temp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp")
Dim LR2 As Long

ws.Range("D1:D" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Temp.Range("U1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Temp.Range("U1").RemoveDuplicates 1, xlYes
    LR2 = Temp.Range("U" & Temp.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Get_Params = Temp.Range("U2:U" & LR2).Value '<--- ERROR HERE (LR2 = 2)

    Temp.Range("U1").EntireColumn.ClearContents

End Function
```

Comment: I have also tried `Erase Params` on main sub before re-assigning the array but I get the same issue. Have also tried `Params = ""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is declared as an array see `As Variant()`

```
Function Get_Params(ws As Worksheet, LR As Long, Target As Range) As Variant()
```

but `Range("U2:U2").Value` does not return an array but just a normal value because it is only a single cell. Therefore you get a type mismatch error.

#### Solution

Declare your function `As Variant` only:

```
Function Get_Params(ws As Worksheet, LR As Long, Target As Range) As Variant
```

For your variabe `Params` you can then check `If VarType(params) = vbArray Then` to catch both array and non-array return, and handle both as needed.

Comment: This did the trick. Now I am getting an error on my `LBound(Params, 1) to UBound(Params, 1)` since it is no longer an array. Can I force this to just be a 1x1 array? Accepting solution regardless since this addressed the specific question asked.

Comment: @urdearboy see my edit. It might actually also be `If VarType(params) = vbArray + vbVariant Then` not sure.